# How do I copy a String from a &String while iterating through a Vector?

Tags: rust, ownership

I'm trying to get my head around ownership and the borrow checker. I've run into an issue I've managed to 'solve' but I think there should be a more ergonomic way to do it.

The following code trips the borrow checker, because I'm trying to move `file.filepath` to `thisfile_path` while it is in a borrowed context.

```
for file in &self.filelist {
    let thisfile_path = String::from(file.filepath);
    let this_wd = self.notifier.add_watch(Path::new(&file.filepath), watch_mask::CLOSE_WRITE).unwrap();
    let this_watch = Watchlist {configfile: thisfile_path, watchd: this_wd};
    watches.push(this_watch);
}
```

`&self.filelist` is `Vec<ConfigFiles>` where ConfigFiles is a `struct`.

I'm iterating through `filelist`, and I want to copy a field from the ConfigFiles struct to a new `Vec`.

If I replace that line with
`let thisfile_path = String::from(&file.filepath);`
it doesn't work because the trait convert is not implemented for `&String`.

I've found a workaround, but I don't think it's the ideal way to do this:

```
let thisfile_path = String::from(&file.filepath[..]);
```

Is this the only way I can resolve this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`std::string::String` implements the [`clone()` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.clone), so you could achieve the same thing in a more direct way using:

```
let thisfile_path = file.filepath.clone();
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `no method named \`clone\` found for type \`str\` in the current scope`. What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

I have no means to try the code right now and I am not that knowledgeable about Rust myself, but I think [`.to_owned()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html) is what you are looking for. Cloning a reference yields a reference; `.to_owned()` returns the desired datatype.

Comment: *Cloning a reference yields a reference* — only if the referred-to type does not implement `Clone`. *I have no means to try the code right now* —
 https://play.rust-lang.org/

Comment: I have a similar problem. I prefer this answer, personally, to the one above because I don't want to pay the price of cloning a string. I want to move the string to a struct. After I move the string, I have no use for it anymore because I'm looping.

Comment: @FrederickOllinger does `to_owned()` not clone the string?